# Filter Records on Multiple Values

Tags: powershell, filter

I have to get a list of AD users where the **Manager** field contains one of the following names on my `FilterValues` list.

I see that someone recommended to use the `Where-Object`, however when I run the script nothing gets returned. I have tried many approaches but I can't seem to find where I am going wrong. Any advise will be greatly appreciated, TIA.

```
$FilterValues = $('Williams', 'Smith', 'Johnson')

Get-ADUser -Filter "extensionAttribute10 -like '1.0'" -Properties * 
| Where-Object {$_.Manager -contains $FilterValues} 
| Format-Table Name, Manager
```

***  If I run the script without the Where-Object portion I get values back.

Comment: That's not what -contains does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-contains` is for testing values in an array, unlike the string `.Contains()` method. In this case, I'd suggest using the regex `-match` operator like this:

```
# an array of manager names
$FilterValues = 'Williams', 'Smith', 'Johnson'
# create a regular expression of the manager names by combining them with the regex OR symbol '|'
# the [regex]::Escape() is there to make sure characters that have special meaning in regex are escaped.
$regexManagers = ($FilterValues | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

Get-ADUser -Filter "extensionAttribute10 -like '1.0'" -Properties Name, Manager | 
    Where-Object {$_.Manager -match $regexManagers } | 
    Format-Table
```

P.S. It is always a bad idea to search for ALL properties with `-Properties *` when you only want two properties returned.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I will go ahead and work using that... also thank you for the clarification on -contains vs. .Contains() as well as the advice with the properties.